# Connect external monitor to motherboard (FI-X30H to HDMI adater)

Tags: display, motherboard, hdmi, cable, connector

I'm recycling a "all in one" computer. The monitor is broken so I would like to be able to connect the motherboard to an external monitor. I have absolutely zero knowledge in electronics or computer components.

What can I do / what component should I buy to convert the motherboard internal FPC connector (I guess, female) to an HDMI output (female) ?

Specs :

- Computer : Lenovo C445 ([hardware documentation here](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/desktop_pub/lenovo_c345c445_hmm_20130114.pdf)).
- Motherboard :  [Lenovo CFT1A68S 11117-1N](http://images.esellerpro.com/2131/I/829/36/1.jpg)
- Monitor :  [LG Display LM215WF4-TLG1](http://www.beyondinfinite.com/lcd/Library/LG-Philips/LM215WF4-TLG1.pdf) (Full technical information about  FI-X30H and FI-X30HL (JAE) LCD connector are available on page 8)

### Expected result :

Connect any external monitor using a HDMI cable to the motherboard and use it as main display.

### Questions

- What kind of cable / connector / adapter do I need ?

### Motherboard FFC connector:

[image]

### Display reference :

[image]

### Cable informations:

[image]

I previously asked this question on [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/connect-external-monitor-to-motherboard-ffc-connector-to-female-hdmi), marked as off-topic.

Comment: The hardware documentation you linked states some models have an HDMI-out connector. Does yours have that?

Comment: Also, the image of the motherboard you posted from esellerpro.com does not quite match the picture in the documentation drawing. Can you take a picture of your actual motherboard and post it?

Comment: you could also just replace the LCD:  https://www.amazon.com/Display-Matte-Screen-Panel-LM215WF4/dp/B01LZE7XHF

Comment: @wysiwyg, it doesn't have hdmi output unfortunately. The actual motherboard is definitely the same as in the picture (connector is top right corner).

Comment: @Musselman_LL  Thanks, but I'm looking for a cheaper solution. Also, I haven't found a compatible LCD that can be shipped to France.

Comment: @wysiwyg But you'r right, it doesn't exactly match the doc.

Comment: Well, I haven't found a solution to connect an external monitor, but I achieved my purpose anyway, which was to perform an Ubuntu 16.04 installation in order to use that computer as a home server. I managed to setup boot in Legacy mode (blindly), boot on a live-usb and install openssh (still blindly), connect to the live-usb session with ssh and perform a fresh install on local hard drive using remmina, then again boot on hard drive, install ssh and finally, configure my server.